# Running Azure functions will result in .net 4.7.1 installation prompt dialog

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

When I try to run (debug) functions in Visual Studio 2017 on one of our machines, the following dialog pops up!

[image]

The target framework for the project is `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`. For some reasons I am not able to install .NET 4.7.1 and now I am completely lost. I am sure it was functioning in the past on the same machine. Probably one of the updates caused it.

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Could you show me what have you updated? This is the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237105/this-application-requires-one-of-the-following-versions-of-net-framework)

Comment: @JoeyCai I think it was an update for Azure Function Tools for Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the latest version of the [Azure Functions Tools for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs) now requires .NET Framework 4.7.1 (as of February 2018).

Note that this does not impact the target framework that you *compile* against - only the target framework your code *runs* against. Similarly, when you run in Azure, you can expect the .NET runtime version to be .NET Framework 4.7.1 (at the time of writing).

Comment: Thanks but what am I supposed to do? Do I have to I uninstall and then reinstall the old version? I am not able to install the version 4.7.1

Comment: @Mori I think you need to figure out why you're not able to install .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing the solution mentioned in comment. However, it didn't work for me. However, *reverting the Azure Functions Tools to previous version* worked. Thanks Chris for pointing that it was Azure Tools and not any packages that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else should come across this.

For me, the issue was the actual func.exe config that needed to be upgraded.

Navigate to: 
C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases[VERSION]\cli
.. my version was 1.4.0

Modify the func.exe.config to match the .net version installed

.. it was 4.7.1