# How to push local repo to github without errors

Tags: git-for-windows

I am new to Got and so I have been trying to push a repo to github using my Github HTTPS. But it keeps showing me >credential-manager-core.exe - " This application requires one of the following versions of .NET Framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2

Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?"

I have downloaded the .NETFramework but it's giving me error that my Operating System is not supported. I use Git-Bash and Sublime text 3 as my editors

Comment: git-bash is not an editor - it's a port of the Unix/Linux bash to Windows that Git-for-Windows comes with (because Git needs a Unix-style shell). The credential-manager-core thing is also specific to Git-for-Windows. Since I don't use Windows, I can't tell you much more about that. However, you can use ssh instead of https to sidestep this particular issue; whether that's a good idea is another question entirely.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237105/this-application-requires-one-of-the-following-versions-of-net-framework A bunch of solutions to this problem.